# Assigning a default value to each element in an array of struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, c-strings

I need to initialize an array of structs with the same default values. This is a VERY large array, so setting each element by hand in an initializer is not feasable. Is the following code a correct and sane way to do this, or will I need to fall back on some initializer function and a for loop?

```
#define SIZE_OF_S1_ARR 10000 //just some arbitrary size for an example

typedef struct { char* id, char* description} S1;

/*
 * Array of structs, with each element having an id and a description 
 * which is an empty c-string
/*/
S1 s1_arr[SIZE_OF_S1_ARR] = {{ "", "" }};
```

I will add that this array already existed as a char array which only contained the ids as a single character. I am replacing it with the more useful struct.

Comment: Why don't you wrap access to this array and return a default value if `NULL` is found?

Comment: Legacy code with lots of global variable nastiness.

Comment: The "universal zero initializer" works: `S1 s1_arr[SIZE_OF_S1_ARR] = {0};`

Comment: S1 s1_arr[SIZE_OF_S1_ARR] = {0};

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920430/c-array-initialization

Comment: That works in this specific case, but what about with non-empty strings (such as an id of "_")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard C there is not array initiaization other than 0, unless you specify each value separately.

However, if you use the GNU C compiler, you can use something like this:

```
char s1_arr[SIZE_OF_S1_ARR] = {[0 ... SIZE_OF_S1_ARR-1] = '_' };
```

Please note that this approach is not portable.
In addition, please note that initalizing strings (i.e., pointer to char) to have the same value can be done in two ways:
(possible automatically) allocate a number of stings and assign them *or* allocate one string and assign it to all elements

Comment: Though it's a bit late this does seem to be the best solution and possibly the only "real" answer to my question. It is unfortunate that it is not a portable solution.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are looking for the [memset](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) function.

Comment: That is helpful if I am forced to create an initialization function, however I'd rather have this set by the compiler if possible. I do understand this simply may not be a feature of the language, but I am hoping there is a way.

Comment: look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669206/how-to-initialize-members-of-an-array-of-struct-in-c your code would look very odd for 10000 items :)

Comment: I had seen that, however I was hoping against hope that there was another way. I will leave this question up while I work on an initialization function in case someone else can come up a static initialization solution.

Answer (score -2):

To initialize your S1 type

```
#define ARBITER 10000 // just an example number for elements

S1 *s1_arr = (S1*)malloc(sizeof(S1)*ARBITER);
```

`id` and `description` are initialized with `NULL`.

To set `s1_arr->id` and `s1_arr->description` you need also a *char variable

or just a literal string (`char* a_string = "I am a String"; // This is a literal`).

Hope I help you out.

Comment: malloc does *NOT* initialize the memory! for that u need to use `cmalloc()` http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html